# Can I set GnuCash to denominate everything in a security (Bitcoin)?

Tags: gnucash, cryptocurrency

I have all my personal finances in GnuCash. EUR is now my main currency.

The menus allow me to set the main "currency" to, naturally, currencies. I have bitcoin as a security. Can I set my while GnuCash to display everything in Bitcoin?

Comment: See section 12.2.1.1 of the [gnucash manual](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v4/C/gnucash-guide/currency_manual.html).

Comment: @glibdud -- isn´t that an answer?